# Sending Email to Righfax via VB6 api

Tags: vb6

Does anyone know how to send an email to Righfax? We are currently send faxes to Righfax through vb6 api calls, but when I send an email address I get an invalid character in phone number field. But the fax info uses the same field. I don't know how to set the flag to tell it that its an email. Help...someone...please:(

Comment: Could you please provide some more informations? Code? Exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

I've used it years ago and I used the vendor's RightFax api to achieve what you wanted.

The docs for the API are [here](http://fraise.dyndns.org/sites/RFaxUtils/Documentations/rfapi700.pdf).